# Accessing port on Azure VM

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine

I'm running a **VM** on Azure. I first **ssh** into it through my CL, then I build a docker container which opens a Jupyter Notebook which is accessible from http://localhost:8889 *on the VM*.

How do I access this port of the VM through a **browser on my computer**?

I couldn't find much on the web... hopefully I'll be able to access this port of the VM directly from my browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running macOS, Linux, or another Unix-y OS, then `ssh -L 8889:localhost:8889 $USER@$VM` will bind port 8889 on your system with `localhost:8889` on the specified VM. You can then go to `http://localhost:8889` on your system's browser.

If you're running Windows then I can't help you, except to say that you should specify that sort of thing up-front.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm running macOS. I get this output: "Permission denied (publickey)." 
Where should I add the key? Thanks a lot

Comment: The terminal should say that, but does the browser show the right things?

Comment: adding `-i /path/to/your/private/key` to:


`ssh -i /path/to/your/private/key -L 8889:localhost:8889 $USER@$VM`


seems to work, but then localhost:8889 on my mac leads me to an empty Jupyter Notebook... the terminal on the notebook says:


root@myVM:/app# which is empty... it must be something with the volumes...

Comment: The browser shows "This site can't be reached" if I don't add my key...

Comment: What about if you add your key?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my previous comment did't get published. With the key, it works. Thank you. I then had a second issue but that was just a path problem.